# OpenCV and C++: "Can't resolve variable 'Mat`"

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm trying to integrate OpenCV in Android Java native interface using C++ language. I have placed the OpenCV inside the `jni` folder, where I'm writing my C++ code. I have included the Opencv header files in my HelloNative.c file. But I'm still getting this error while trying to access Mat object. 
"`Can't resolve variable Mat`".

I have tried `using namespace cv`, but it gives an error to predeclare `using` and `namespace`; which is not a solution. I'm posting my code below, please somebody have a look at it and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <OpenCV/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <OpenCV/include/opencv/cv.h>
#include <OpenCV/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <OpenCV/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h>
#include <OpenCV/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <OpenCV/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <OpenCV/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <OpenCV/modules/legacy/include/opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
#include <OpenCV/modules/videostab/include/opencv2/videostab/motion_stabilizing.hpp>
#include <OpenCV/modules/videostab/include/opencv2/videostab/global_motion.hpp>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_soimporttest_MainActivity_getStringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj,
                                                            jstring imagepath) {
    const char *jnamestr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, imagepath, 0);
    int width, height, gray;
    FILE *fp = fopen(jnamestr, "rb");
    if (fp) {
        //Read .pgm file
        int scan = fscanf(fp, "P5%d%d%d", &width, &height, &gray);
        if (scan != 3 || &gray > 256 || &width > 0xfffff || &height > 0xfffff || &gray <= 1 ||
            &width < 32 || &height < 32) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 9;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_soimporttest_MainActivity_displayImage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jclass type, jlong inpAddr, jlong outAddr) {
    ::Mat &src = *(Mat*)inpAddr;
    Mat &dst = *(Mat*)outAddr;
    applyFilter(src , dst);
}
```

There are two functions in this file, the first function `getStringFromJNI` is working perfectly fine. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Please show us how you compile the file.
And are your doing C or C++? Those languages are **NOT** the same.

Comment: I'm compiling it using `ndk-build`. I was supposed to use C for JNI but openCV integrates in C++. So I'm mixing up both languages in one file. If you can help me find, how to integrate opencv in C or jni; it will be best.

Comment: Can't you just replace every use of `Mat` in your C++ code with `cv::Mat`?

Comment: Also, _"it gives an error to predeclare using and namespace"_ is not very clear. What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template) I made to set up native OpenCV with Android, hope it helps!

Comment: Hi vSomers: thank you for your kind support. I did exactly the same as you mentioned in the tutorial but getting the following error:
 ```ninja: error: '/app/src/main/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java4.so', needed by 'D:/Junaid_workspace/native-opencv-android-template-master/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I finally managed to find out a good solution for my question. Please follow below mentioned tutorial:
https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio
You'll be facing some issues while integrating it. You can post those solutions in the comments and I will guide you through each.
Thanks.